# Change Field Properties in table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access "Make Table" query that concatenates a SharePoint library URL and the path to each document uploaded. The result, however, is output as a Text field. Currently I have to manually change the field property from Text to Hyperlink in order to have the output displayed as the document name, with a hyperlink to the document. Is there a way to change the field property using a query?

Comment: Can you post the SQL of your Make Table query?  It will be easier to point out the proper way to do it if we can see the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

As HansUp mentions, there is no way to do the conversion in SQL alone, but if you run a VBA procedure immediately after executing the make-table query it can "convert" the field for you.

(It actually has to create a new field, copy over the link data enclosed in `#` characters, drop the old field, and then rename the new one.)

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertFieldToHyperlink()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set tbd = cdb.TableDefs("yourTable")
    Set fld = New DAO.Field
    fld.Name = "zzzNew"
    fld.Type = vbVariant
    fld.Attributes = dbHyperlinkField
    tbd.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = Nothing
    cdb.Execute "UPDATE [yourTable] SET [zzzNew]='#' & [linkField] & '#'", dbFailOnError
    tbd.Fields.Delete "linkField"
    tbd.Fields("zzzNew").Name = "linkField"
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and thank you Gord for sending me the code! I'm sorry for the late response, however I needed some time to understand what I have to do with it. I have entered the code in a module, I have updated the information to reflect my table information. And then when I run it I get the error: Run-time error "3259": Invalid field data type. The error comes for fld.Type = adVariant. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @user3020843 Hmm, perhaps it should be `fld.Type = vbVariant`. Try that instead. Also, check the top of your Module to ensure that includes the `Option Explicit` statement as illustrated in my answer. (It's important.)

Answer (score 1):

[The Hyperlink type field cannot be created with DDL.](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html#_ftn9) That Access SQL limitation applies regardless of whether you want to create a field or alter the type of an existing field.  So your make table query can create a text field, but *not* a hyperlink field.

Separately, you could run VBA code to alter the field type in the table's DAO `TableDef`.  However, I think it should be easier to create the destination table structure once and then load your data into that table.  In other words, use an *"append query"* instead of a *"make table"* query.  If you later need to replace the data in that table, don't drop the table and create a new version.  Just `DELETE` the existing rows and then append the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat operator (`&`) to manually create an `href` element:

```
SELELCT '<a href="' & link & '">' & name & '</a>'
FROM    documents
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my knowledge of access is limited to simple qieries and your ansewer got me really confused. It looks like another way to concatinate the URL and the documents' name, while the concatination I do works, but the issue is that I get the result as text, while I need it as hyperlink. When I change it manualy the link to the documents is displayed as the name of the document and it is a hyperlink. Would you please share more information of what the query statement is about and how to get is started?